# Make form field required if other form field is set

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to have the POC field be a required field  if the location is set to Deployed, but not if it is set to Local. I tried this below:

```
<%= form_with(model: hardware, local: true, multipart: true) do |form| %>
<% if hardware.errors.any? %>
   <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(hardware.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this hardware from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% hardware.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= form.label "Location" %>
  <%= form.select :location, ['Local', 'Deployed'] %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= form.label "POC" %>
  <% if (:location == 'Deployed')%>
    <%= form.collection_select(:poc_id, Poc.all, :id, :name, { :prompt => 'Select a POC', :selected => @hardware.poc_id,  include_blank: true }, { class: 'form-control', required: true }) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= form.collection_select(:poc_id, Poc.all, :id, :name, { :prompt => 'Select a POC', :selected => @hardware.poc_id,  include_blank: true }, { class: 'form-control' }) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

When I run it like this, it does not give any errors, but does not require the field. The only difference between the two collection selects is at the end where I set the required: true flag for the if statement and have it off on the else statement.

Is there a way to do this with the method I am trying? Are there any Ruby Form Helpers that will allow the feature? Do I need to use Javascript to implement this feature?

Comment: Yes, you should use Javascript. By the way, `if :location == 'Deployed'` is incorrect, it should be `if hardware.location == "Deployed"`. Also you could remove duplication with the existing code using `required: (hardware.location == "Deployed")`, no need for the conditional block.